# Cannot get the execution time of change directory 'cd' command by 'time'?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, unix, command-line

I want to evaluate the overhead of `autojump`-like commands as

```
time cd /tmp
time z /tmp
time autojump /tmp
```

However, there is no output like `time ls`'s

```
ls -G  0.00s user 0.00s system 66% cpu 0.007 total
```

Why the `time` command behaves like that, and is there a way to measure the running time of `cd` command?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: cd is a builtin, it just calls `chdir`. what is the point of timing it?

Comment: try `time /usr/bin/cd /tmp`

Comment: @RomeoNinov, `time /usr/bin/cd /tmp` works. But why it gets output only when the full path of `cd` is provided.

Comment: @DaiZhang, you can check my answer

Comment: @oguzismail for some directories `cd ...` takes a long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of such behavior is you run two build-in command: `time` and `cd`. And because of this you can't measure precisely the times.

For this and a lot of other reasons there is dedicated executable `/usr/bin/time` which you can use. Also you have `/usr/bin/cd`.

So try your commands on this way:

```
/usr/bin/time cd /tmp
/usr/bin/time z /tmp
/usr/bin/time autojump /tmp
```

[Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11465/101265) you can find more detailed info about the difference between build-in and external commands.

Comment: When testing `cd` and `time` using `which` command, I got `cd: shell built-in command` and `time: shell reserved word`. And when changing one of them to full-path `/usr/bin/*`-like representation, I can get the running time output.

Comment: What's the difference between a build-in command and an executable file?

Comment: @DaiZhang, most of build commands have dedicated executables. The difference is you have less executable time/load (by some %) when build-in and in some cases more options (for external). In some cases (as above) you are forced to use external one.

Comment: @DaiZhang, you can check here for more detailed info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11465/101265